# Laravel Integration with Webix Datatable Editing

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.1, webix

I have a site that's running Laravel 5 and I'd like to create a Webix datatable within it. My understanding of Webix datatables is that these tables can be set to load data from Laravel database by using a controller, but I do not see any information on how datatable information is read and saved when the datatable is set to editable.

When the datatable is editable, do I still need to create a controller for read and write to the database? And if so, how do I know what data was changed/needs to be updated in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For examples on how to load and save data in php, have a look at these:

http://docs.webix.com/desktop__custom_serverside.html#dataloading
http://docs.webix.com/desktop__dataconnector.html
http://docs.webix.com/samples/14_dataprocessor/08_custom_urls.html

For the javascript side using webix you can call `save`

```
dtable = new webix.ui({
    container:"test",
    view:"datatable",
    editable: true
    columns:[
        { id:"id", header:"Id", width:80},
        { id:"name", header:"Name", width:100},
        { id:"email", header:"Email", width:100}
    ],
    url: "data/data_load.php",
    datatype:"json" //can be omitted if json.
    save: {
        "insert":"data/data_insert.php",
        "update":"data/data_update.php",
        "delete":"data/data_delete.php"
    }
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://docs.webix.com/samples/40_serverside/01_php_vanila/03_datatable_reordering.html) calling save on reordering (check the source code, and POST requests which calls `datatable_order_save.php`).

Or you can use `onAfterEditStop` combined with some ajax post, which should allow you to ignore if the update failed.

```
on: {
    onAfterEditStop: function(state, editor, ignoreUpdate){
        if(state.value != state.old){
            // some $ajax() post to update values
        }  
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.